# Syntax errors when installing Composer?

Tags: php, linux, curl, command-line, composer-php

I have tried to start installing composer using each of these

`sudo -u myuser curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`

`sudo -u myuser curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --check`

But both give me

```
Warning: Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in - on line 381

Warning: Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in - on line 386

Warning: Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in - on line 402

Warning: Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in - on line 640

Warning: Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in - on line 688

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_SL in - on line 814
```

Anyone seen this before?

I'm running Linux 3.1.9-vs2.3.2.5vs2.3.2.5+  and PHP 5.2.17 (cli)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using a php command line version that does not understand namespaces: 5.2.17. Composer can only run with PHP 5.3 and up.

Note that that version you run on the command line need not have anything to do with the PHP you are using in the web server itself. It usually is a different executable with it's own configuration.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! This is definitely the case- I have spoken more than once with my host about when the CLI version of PHP will be updated.  No sites on the server are allowed to use 5.2 anymore but 5.3 is not available from command line.  I feel very foolish that I did not notice this earlier:  https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#system-requirements